# How to find a particular solution using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm looking for a way to find a specific solution to a differential equation. As a simplified version of my problem, here's a similar setup for a simple harmonic oscillator problem.

```
aargh = 
  NDSolve[{
   -0.000000000001 + q''[x] == -q[x], 
   q'[π] == q'[-π], q[-π] == q[π]}, 
   q, {x, -π, π}];
Plot[Evaluate[q[x] /. aargh], {x, -π, π}]
```

The reason for the 0.00000000001 is to perturb the system slightly to ensure that I get a nonzero solution. 
This gives a beautiful harmonic function as a solution. Now, what I want to do, is specify a starting trial solution for `NDSolve` to look around. For example, say I wanted to find the $\sin(x)$ solution to the differential equation. Is there any way by which I can specify this and ask *Mathematica* to look around a particular function for my solution.

My actual problem is far more complicated, but is essentially the same. It is also homogenous, so I've added a perturbation there as well to find the non zero solution. Once again, *Mathematica* is returning an approximately valid solution, but I know that there exists another solution somewhere else. How do I tell *Mathematica* to look there?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48797/12)  The idea is to make `q` depend on another variable as well ("time") and construct the equation so that you get the solution of your boundary value problem at `t -> Infinity`.  Now you have a PDE and it's possible to set an initial condition.

Comment: There's a two-dimensional family of solutions to your BVP, ``1.`*^-12 + C[1] Sin[x] + C[2] Cos[x]``.  I think the *NDSolve* methods for BVPs expect the solution to be unique (or perhaps a discrete set).  (Execute `DSolve[{-10^-12 + q''[x] == -q[x], q[π] == q[-π], q'[-π] == q'[π]}, q, x]` and examine the warning messages and solution.)

Comment: It seems that you might replace `q`by anothe variable, such as `q[x]=Sin[x]+z[x]`and reformulate your problem in terms of `z[x]`. This will explicitly mean "to look around".

Comment: @Szabolcs: Hmm. Yes, that does seem similar to what i'm trying to do. I'll try that out and get back to you on the results..

Comment: @MichaelE2: Yes, I understand that in this particular sample problem there is an entire family of solutions. I want to make Mathematica converge to a preferable member of that family rather than an arbitrary one.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: That's in interesting approach. I'll try that as well and get back to you on the results..